# Access GPIO3 pins via PRU on Beaglebone Black

Tags: assembly, interrupt, beagleboneblack, gpio, device-tree

I am trying to port a Sample-Project from [Beaglebone Black PRU code for HC-SR04 sonar](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=beaglebone%20black%20hcsr04), which works totally fine to other GPIO pins. I need to setup multiple sonars on my BBB. So I deciced to use for example pin P9_31 and P9_25. I adapted the dts- and c-file. Everything is correctly loaded (pins, pin functions and the overlay as such). But now don't know what exactly needs to be modified in the pru assambler file. Simply switching to GPIO3 base address and adapting the pin bit did not work out. Here are my adaptions to the p-file.

```
// Define the entry point of the program
.origin 0
.entrypoint START

// Address of the io controller for GPIO1 and GPIO2
#define GPIO1 0x4804C000
#define GPIO2 0x481AC000
#define GPIO3 0x481AE000

// Offset address for the output enable register of the gpio controller
#define GPIO_OE 0x134

// Offset address for the data in/out register of the gpio controller
#define GPIO_DATAIN 0x138
#define GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT 0x190
#define GPIO_SETDATAOUT 0x194

// PRU interrupt for PRU0 and PRU1
#define PRU0_ARM_INTERRUPT 19
#define PRU1_ARM_INTERRUPT 20

// original code
// gpio1[12] P8_12 gpio44 0x030
//#define BIT_TRIGGER 0x0C

// gpio1[13] P8_11 gpio45 0x034
//#define BIT_ECHO 0x0D
// end of original code

// gpio3[14] P9_31 gpio110 0x6B
#define BIT_ECHO 0x0E    // gpio3_14 -> gpio pin 110

// gpio2[7] P9_25 gpio117 0x03
#define BIT_TRIGGER 0x0B   // gpio3_21 gpio pin 117

#define delay r0
#define roundtrip r4


START:

    // Clear the STANDBY_INIT bit in the SYSCFG register
    // otherwise the PRU will not be able to write outside the PRU memory space
    // and to the Beaglebone pins
    LBCO r0, C4, 4, 4
    CLR r0, r0, 4
    SBCO r0, C4, 4, 4

    // Make constant 24 (c24) point to the beginning of PRU0 data ram
    MOV r0, 0x00000000
    MOV r1, 0x22020
    SBBO r0, r1, 0, 4

    // Enable trigger as output and echo as input (clear BIT_TRIGGER and set BIT_ECHO of output enable)
    MOV r3, GPIO3 | GPIO_OE
    LBBO r2, r3, 0, 4
    CLR r2, BIT_TRIGGER
    SET r2, BIT_ECHO
    SBBO r2, r3, 0, 4

TRIGGER:

    // Fire the sonar
    // Set trigger pin to high
    MOV r2, 1<<BIT_TRIGGER
    MOV r3, GPIO3 | GPIO_SETDATAOUT
    SBBO r2, r3, 0, 4

    // Delay 10 microseconds (200 MHz / 2 instructions = 10 ns per loop, 10 us = 1000 loops) 
    MOV delay, 1000
TRIGGER_DELAY:
    SUB delay, delay, 1
    QBNE TRIGGER_DELAY, delay, 0

    // Set trigger pin to low
    MOV r2, 1<<BIT_TRIGGER
    MOV r3, GPIO3 | GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT
    SBBO r2, r3, 0, 4

    // Wait for BIT_ECHO to go high, i.e. wait for the echo cycle to start
    MOV r3, GPIO3 | GPIO_DATAIN
WAIT_ECHO:
    // Read the GPIO until BIT_ECHO goes high
    LBBO r2, r3, 0, 4
    QBBC WAIT_ECHO, r2, BIT_ECHO

    // roundtrip measures the echo duration in microseconds, resolution is 1us
    MOV roundtrip, 0

SAMPLE_ECHO:

    // Delay 1 microsecond (adjusted because it takes time to query the GPIO pin)
    MOV delay, 76
SAMPLE_ECHO_DELAY:
    SUB delay, delay, 1
    QBNE SAMPLE_ECHO_DELAY, delay, 0

    // Add 1us to the roundtrip counter
    ADD roundtrip, roundtrip, 1

    // Read GPIO until BIT_ECHO goes low
    LBBO r2, r3, 0, 4
    QBBS SAMPLE_ECHO, r2, BIT_ECHO

    // Echo is complete
    // Store the microsecond count in the PRU's data ram so C program can read it
    SBCO roundtrip, c24, 0, 4

    // Trigger the PRU0 interrupt (C program gets the event)
    MOV r31.b0, PRU0_ARM_INTERRUPT+16

    // Delay to allow sonar to stop resonating and sound burst to decay in environment
    MOV delay, 3000000
RESET_DELAY:
    SUB delay, delay, 1
    QBNE RESET_DELAY, delay, 0

    // Jump back to triggering the sonar
    JMP TRIGGER

    HALT
```

I am working on a BBB Rev C.1 running Debian with kernel 3.8.13 (bone47).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue: I moved the trigger pin to P9_27 which makes the defines in .p file to:

```
 // Define the entry point of the program
 .origin 0
 .entrypoint START

 // Address of the io controller for GPIO1 and GPIO2
 #define GPIO1 0x4804C000
 #define GPIO2 0x481AC000
 #define GPIO3 0x481AE000

 // Offset address for the output enable register of the gpio controller
 #define GPIO_OE 0x134

 // Offset address for the data in/out register of the gpio controller
 #define GPIO_DATAIN 0x138
 #define GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT 0x190
 #define GPIO_SETDATAOUT 0x194

 // PRU interrupt for PRU0 and PRU1
 #define PRU0_ARM_INTERRUPT 19
 #define PRU1_ARM_INTERRUPT 20

 // gpio3[14] P9_31 gpio110 0x6B
 #define BIT_ECHO 0x0E// gpio3_14 -> gpio pin 110

 // gpio3[19] P9_27 gpio115 0x03
 #define BIT_TRIGGER 0x13   // gpio3_19 -> gpio pin 115

 #define delay r0
 #define roundtrip r4
```

But the actual fault was a wrong pin offset in my dts file. So the PRU code works now